# CRC 16 Modbus RTU

Tags: modbus

Can someone provide an example of C code for calculating CRC. This is the string to send 01 04 30 00 00 01. Correct CRC this is 3E CA.
I tried looking around the internet and tried to calculate the CRC with pen and paper but again I get a different CRC than the one provided example below.
At this point I think I don't understand or I'm missing something on how to calculate it.
The driver I'm trying to make needs to send this data
/* ID ADDRESS    2 bytes
* FUNCTION CODE 2 bytes
* START ADDRESS 2 bytes
* N BYTE READ   2 bytes
* CRC           2 bytes
*/

Comment: You do realize that the ID address and the function code and etc. are all one byte? The data is N bytes and CRC is 2 bytes, but the other ones you mention here are all 8 bits - 2 hex digits - 1 byte.

Comment: I write you the best formatted code so you can understand me. Device id is 1 so we can also write it as 0x0001, function code is 4 (0x0004), start address 0x3000, N BYTE READ is 1 (0x0001). I only need to read one log. I have already tried before but when I do the calculations they are wrong.

Comment: "so we can also write it as 0x0001" well you can but that would be confusing because I'd read that as a two bytes (`00` followed by `01`) whereas the spec states that the Address is 8 bits (a byte, so sending a two bytes, "ID ADDRESS 2 bytes", is not a valid Modbus request). If your specific device expects two bytes for each of the ID and function code then it's using something other than Modbus (and the CRC algorithm might not match the Modbus one). The [Modbus spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) includes an example CRC implementation in C (page 42).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. With your feedback and the code provided by the guy below everything works fine and I realized the mistake I made, it was a little oversight. For the field N BYTE READ instead of sending 0x00 followed by 0x01 I sent only 0x01

Comment: No worries; I'd suggest accepting the answer as it does provide an example as you requested (as you did not provide code we had no way of knowing the real issue).

Answer (score 0):

The snippet from [*Continental Control Systems, LLC*](https://ctlsys.com/support/how_to_compute_the_modbus_rtu_message_crc/) works fine for me, I get the right CRC, you just have to swap the order of the 2 bytes. Here it is:

```
// Compute the MODBUS RTU CRC
uint16_t ModRTU_CRC(uint8_t[] buf, int len)
{
  uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;
  
  for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
    crc ^= (uint16_t)buf[pos];          // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc
  
    for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {    // Loop over each bit
      if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {      // If the LSB is set
        crc >>= 1;                    // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
        crc ^= 0xA001;
      }
      else                            // Else LSB is not set
        crc >>= 1;                    // Just shift right
    }
  }
  /* Note, this number has low and high bytes swapped, so use it accordingly (or swap bytes - 
  here is a simple example: crc =  ((crc>>8) | (crc<<8); <- simple swap, if you need it */
  
return crc;
 
}
```